# Why are my 2 new windows 7 (64 bit) workstations taking over 10 minutes to log on to the SBS 2008 domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows-sbs-2008, login

we have a SBS 2008 domain. On this we have windows XP clients. However, we are testing the windows 7 (64 bit) machines on the network.

It takes between 10 & 15 minutes to log on - every time!

I have checked the event logs on the client machine, and the only error I can see is;

Event ID: 6005
The winlogon notification subscriber  is took 615 seconds to handle the notification event (CreateSession).

I have no warnings in the server event log, everything pings ok by name, so am guessing DNS is fine.

Can someone please lend a hand with this, as we really want to go with windows 7.

Lastly, both the server, and the windows 7 machines are fully patched and updated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check your DNS settings on these machines. This problem is often caused by the client not having the SBS Machine as its primary DNS server.

Comment: Also, check all the rest of the IP configuration (make sure you check IPv6 options as Win7 favors IPv6 over IPv4 if it's configured).

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing anything in your login scripts that violates UAC?  Try disabling UAC, and rebooting (this is necessary for the UAC change) and see if it still takes 10 minutes.
Windows 7 does not show status of login scripts when the UAC fails and so you have no idea what is going on...at least that's been our experience.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this with Vista and it turned out to be two possibilities

The network driver was the MS one.  Updating to the newest vendor-provided one improved performance significantly

The other was related to logon scripts and policy. Are logon scripts applied to this machine?  Is the policy “Run logon scripts synchronously” enabled.  We  temporarily disabled the policy or remove the logon scripts to check the result.

Saw others with this issue that teh above did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a situation similar to this when I was running the Windows 7 beta against my SBS 2003 server. When I installed Windows 7 RC (a clean install), the problem went away so I assumed the problem was caused by 'baggage' from the upgraded Windows Vista installation. Anyway, I never discovered the root cause and it hasn't re-occurred since, I have several Windows 7 machines on that domain now and they are all just fine.

Were tha machines upgraded or nuked-and-paved? Upgrades often come at the cost of a lot of 'baggage' and a clean install, though inconvenient, is always better in the long run, in my experience. Can you try a clean install and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Hi Tim, many thanks for your answer. The two machines are brand new, delivered from dell, all pre loaded. I should not have thought that would be a major issue ? I will get round to answering the other posts on here as I test their theory's and report back with the results. :-) Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Windows 7 logon to a SBS server.

Found online documents suggesting the issue was due to Windows Managment Instrumention log being scanned on startup.  Ran two hotfixes which were listed as solutions Hotfix 435137 and Hotfix 437953 for Win 7 x32.

Also set Network Location Awareness service to manual startup.

One of these two steps resolved the issues for this computer.

Very strange problem, the logon to the domain was taking 10-20 minutes.